# How can I move my static folder to an url with a prefix with flask-restx

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restx

I am trying to deploy an app flask using flask-restx package and I am stuck on how to display properly the documentation on the prod server. It works well locally without any prefix, but on the server, the files url need to be prefixed by `my-prefix` and I am struggling to make the swaggerui files accessible from the url : `url/my-prefix`

Here is my code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(
          app,
          version='3.0',
          title='My API',
          description='My API',
          doc="/my-prefix/docs/",
          prefix="/my-prefix",
          base_url="/my-prefix"
)
```

With this I get the `swagger.json` at the good url but not with the right reference in the code source of the documentation page. The swaggerui files are not well referenced in the code source oof the documentation page and not at the accessible from  `url/my-prefix/swaggerui/files`.

So I have added this :

```
@apidoc.apidoc.add_app_template_global
def swagger_static(filename):
     return f"/my-prefix/swaggerui/{filename}"


api = Api(
          app,
          version='3.0',
          title='My API',
          description='My API',
          doc="/my-prefix/docs/",
          prefix="/my-prefix",
          base_url="/my-prefix"
)


@api.documentation
def custom_ui():
     return render_template("swagger-ui.html", title=api.title, specs_url="/my-prefix/swagger.json")
```

With this, the swaggerui files and the swagger.json file are conveniently referenced in the code source of the documentation page (`url/my-prefix/swaggerui/myfile` and `url/my-prefix/swagger.json`) but the swaggerui files are not reachable from this url. Do you know what I should add to make it accessible at this url : `url/my-prefix/swaggerui/myfile`

Comment: how are you trying to deploy?

Comment: did you manage to get this working ?

Comment: Exact same issue, any update?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done through Apidoc `static_url_path` override

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api
from flask_restx.apidoc import apidoc


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(
          app,
          version='3.0',
          title='My API',
          description='My API',
          doc="/my-prefix/docs/""
)

apidoc.static_url_path = "/my-prefix/swaggerui"
```

Comment: I had to move ```apidoc.static_url_path = "/my-prefix/swaggerui"``` before creating the api.